# Disassembling MS DOS code

Tags: ida, msdos

```
cseg01:0001F4D8                 mov     Disk_Letter, 43h ; 'C'
cseg01:0001F4DF
cseg01:0001F4DF loc_1F4DF:                              ; CODE XREF: sub_1F4C8+60j
cseg01:0001F4DF                 xor     eax, eax
cseg01:0001F4E1                 mov     al, Disk_Letter
cseg01:0001F4E6                 push    eax
cseg01:0001F4E7                 push    offset aCDataTitle_phd ; "%c:\\data\\title.phd"
cseg01:0001F4EC                 lea     eax, [esp+2Ch+var_24]
cseg01:0001F4F0                 push    eax
cseg01:0001F4F1                 call    sprintf_
cseg01:0001F4F6                 add     esp, 0Ch
cseg01:0001F4F9                 mov     edx, offset aRb_4 ; "rb"
cseg01:0001F4FE                 mov     eax, esp
cseg01:0001F500                 call    fopen_
cseg01:0001F505                 test    eax, eax
cseg01:0001F507                 jz      short loc_1F517
cseg01:0001F509                 call    fclose_
cseg01:0001F50E                 call    sub_1F544
cseg01:0001F513                 test    eax, eax
cseg01:0001F515                 jnz     short loc_1F53E
cseg01:0001F517
cseg01:0001F517 loc_1F517:                              ; CODE XREF: sub_1F4C8+3Fj
cseg01:0001F517                 mov     dl, Disk_Letter
cseg01:0001F51D                 inc     dl
cseg01:0001F51F                 mov     Disk_Letter, dl
cseg01:0001F525                 cmp     dl, 5Ah ; 'Z'
cseg01:0001F528                 jbe     short loc_1F4DF
```

```
cseg01:0001F544 sub_1F544       proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_1F4C8+46p
cseg01:0001F544
cseg01:0001F544 var_19          = byte ptr -19h
cseg01:0001F544 var_10          = byte ptr -10h
cseg01:0001F544
cseg01:0001F544                 push    ebx
cseg01:0001F545                 push    edx
cseg01:0001F546                 sub     esp, 10h
cseg01:0001F549                 xor     ebx, ebx
cseg01:0001F54B
cseg01:0001F54B loc_1F54B:                              ; CODE XREF: sub_1F544+26j
cseg01:0001F54B                 call    GetRandomControl
cseg01:0001F550                 imul    edx, eax, 1Ah
cseg01:0001F553                 mov     eax, edx
cseg01:0001F555                 sar     edx, 1Fh
cseg01:0001F558                 shl     edx, 0Fh
cseg01:0001F55B                 sbb     eax, edx
cseg01:0001F55D                 sar     eax, 0Fh
cseg01:0001F560                 inc     ebx
cseg01:0001F561                 add     al, 41h ; 'A'
cseg01:0001F563                 mov     [esp+ebx+18h+var_19], al
cseg01:0001F567                 cmp     ebx, 8
cseg01:0001F56A                 jl      short loc_1F54B
cseg01:0001F56C                 xor     ah, ah
cseg01:0001F56E                 mov     [esp+18h+var_10], ah
cseg01:0001F572                 mov     eax, esp
cseg01:0001F574                 mov     edx, offset aWb ; "wb"
cseg01:0001F579                 call    sub_1F4A4
cseg01:0001F57E                 mov     ebx, eax
cseg01:0001F580                 call    fopen_
cseg01:0001F585                 test    eax, eax
cseg01:0001F587                 jz      short loc_1F599
cseg01:0001F589                 call    fclose_
cseg01:0001F58E                 mov     eax, ebx
cseg01:0001F590                 call    j_unlink_
cseg01:0001F595                 xor     eax, eax
cseg01:0001F597                 jmp     short loc_1F59E
cseg01:0001F599 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cseg01:0001F599
cseg01:0001F599 loc_1F599:                              ; CODE XREF: sub_1F544+43j
cseg01:0001F599                 mov     eax, 1
cseg01:0001F59E
cseg01:0001F59E loc_1F59E:                              ; CODE XREF: sub_1F544+53j
cseg01:0001F59E                 add     esp, 10h
cseg01:0001F5A1                 pop     edx
cseg01:0001F5A2                 pop     ebx
cseg01:0001F5A3                 retn
cseg01:0001F5A3 sub_1F544       endp
```

```
cseg01:0002043C GetRandomControl proc near              ; CODE XREF: sub_1BB1C+3Cp
cseg01:0002043C                                         ; sub_1D754+40p ...
cseg01:0002043C                 imul    eax, rand_2, 41C64E6Dh
cseg01:00020446                 add     eax, 3039h
cseg01:0002044B                 mov     rand_2, eax
cseg01:00020450                 sar     eax, 0Ah
cseg01:00020453                 and     eax, 7FFFh
cseg01:00020458                 retn
cseg01:00020458 GetRandomControl endp
```

```
cseg01:0001F4A4 sub_1F4A4       proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_10ED0+6Bp
cseg01:0001F4A4                                         ; sub_1E2EC+Cp ...
cseg01:0001F4A4                 push    eax
cseg01:0001F4A5                 xor     eax, eax
cseg01:0001F4A7                 mov     al, Disk_Letter
cseg01:0001F4AC                 push    eax
cseg01:0001F4AD                 push    offset aCS      ; "%c:\\%s"
cseg01:0001F4B2                 push    offset unk_CE5FC
cseg01:0001F4B7                 call    sprintf_
cseg01:0001F4BC                 mov     eax, offset unk_CE5FC
cseg01:0001F4C1                 add     esp, 10h
cseg01:0001F4C4                 retn
cseg01:0001F4C4 sub_1F4A4       endp
```

Disassembling MS DOS game (C++ WATCOM compiler 32 bit). I not understand what give to us calling GetRandomControl and how arranged CD ROM device check in function sub_1F544?

Comment: we have no idea what your goals are - "what give to us calling GetRandomControl" - do you want to know what the function returns? "and how to arrange CD ROM device check"  - do you want to disable a CD check? please write at least some sentences, what game, what goals, do you just want to analyse the game, reverse it, patch it - its not clear

Answer (score 0):

This code below produce 8 random letters for file name. A very interesting division algorithm with a remainder of 26 - 1Ah (the number of letters in the alphabet). Function GetRandomControl returns random number (based on time() and localtime()).

```
cseg01:0001F54B loc_1F54B:                              ; CODE XREF: sub_1F544+26j
cseg01:0001F54B                 call    GetRandomControl
cseg01:0001F550                 imul    edx, eax, 1Ah
cseg01:0001F553                 mov     eax, edx
cseg01:0001F555                 sar     edx, 1Fh
cseg01:0001F558                 shl     edx, 0Fh
cseg01:0001F55B                 sbb     eax, edx
cseg01:0001F55D                 sar     eax, 0Fh
cseg01:0001F560                 inc     ebx
cseg01:0001F561                 add     al, 41h ; 'A'
cseg01:0001F563                 mov     [esp+ebx+18h+var_19], al
cseg01:0001F567                 cmp     ebx, 8
cseg01:0001F56A                 jl      short loc_1F54B
```

This code below trying this filename to write on the current disk. If write operation is failed - this is CD. unlink function delete file if write operation succes (this is not CD).

```
cseg01:0001F56C                 xor     ah, ah
cseg01:0001F56E                 mov     [esp+18h+var_10], ah
cseg01:0001F572                 mov     eax, esp
cseg01:0001F574                 mov     edx, offset aWb ; "wb"
cseg01:0001F579                 call    sub_1F4A4
cseg01:0001F57E                 mov     ebx, eax
cseg01:0001F580                 call    fopen_
cseg01:0001F585                 test    eax, eax
cseg01:0001F587                 jz      short loc_1F599
cseg01:0001F589                 call    fclose_
cseg01:0001F58E                 mov     eax, ebx
cseg01:0001F590                 call    j_unlink_
```

By analogy algorithm to produce 8 random letters on C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <time.h>

int rand_2;

int GetRandomDraw( void )
{
    rand_2 = rand_2 * 0x41c64e6d + 0x3039;
    return( ( rand_2 >> 10 )&0x7fff );
}

int main(void)
{
    struct tm   *tptr;
    time_t      lt;

    lt = time(NULL);
    tptr = localtime(&lt);
    rand_2 = tptr->tm_sec+(tptr->tm_min*43)+(tptr->tm_hour*3477);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    {

        int val = GetRandomDraw();

        val = val % 26;

        char ch_my = (unsigned char) val + 0x41;

        printf("%c", ch_my);

    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there still a question?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks.